# Resetting a Matlab timer object to time 0

Tags: matlab, timer

I use a Matlab timer object to rotate some log files at a fixed interval (every 1800 seconds):

```
rotateTimer = timer( ...
    'Name', 'Log Rotator', ...
    'Period', 1800, ...
    'StartDelay', 1800, ...
    'ExecutionMode', 'fixedSpacing', ...
    'TimerFcn', {@RotateLogs});
start(rotateTimer);
```

This method works very well for automatic rotations, but I need to allow the user to manually rotate the log files.

When a manual rotation occurs, I want the next automatic rotation to occur 1800 seconds later; this requires that I "reset" the timer object to begin counting up from 0 at the moment of manual rotation.

I don't see a property or method I can invoke that will zero the timer. Starting and stopping the timer does not reset it, it just continues counting from where it was. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way which does not require to recreate the timer object:

```m
per = 2;
t = timer('Period'       , per, ...
          'StartDelay'   , per, ...
          'ExecutionMode', 'fixedSpacing',...
          'TimerFcn'     , 'disp(toc);tic;',...
          'StopFcn'      , {@mystop,per},...
          'StartFcn'     , 'tic;');

% Suppress warning from millisecond precision of StartDelay
warning('off','MATLAB:TIMER:STARTDELAYPRECISION')

start(t)
stop(t)
delete(t)
```

where `mystop()` is

```m
function mystop(obj,event,in)
    t = toc;
    set(obj,'StartDelay',in-t);
    disp(t)     % Not necessary, just to check
    tic         % Not necessary, just to check 
end
```

The idea here, is that, you can reset the `StartDelay` after each stop and to do that you need to time the elapsed time between each timer execution. This means that you have to reset at each execution.

**REMARKs**:

- the reset at `StartFcn()` is to prevent negative `StartDelay` from previously called `tic` (if applies).
- the `disp(toc)` in `TimerFcn` is not necessary and is just to check that the timings are ok.
- same checking purpose serve the two commented lines in `mystop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am just misunderstanding what you are saying, but can't you just use the 'set' command to 0 the timer?

via Command Window:

```
help timer
...
Getting and setting parameters:
    get              - Get value of timer object property.
    set              - Set value of timer object property.
```

So when a manual rotation occurs, just set the timer back to 0

Comment: The `set` command accepts parameter/value pairs only. I need a parameter name to set, and I don't see one that applies to the value of the timer's counter.

Comment: hmmm I see what you mean, sorry about that. you are correct; there does not seem to be an object property that applies to the timer counter value (which seems very odd to me). I know this may be a very unattractive way of doing things, but have you thought about just deleting the timer when a manual rotation occurs and reinitializing it? if manual_rotation delete(rotateTimer) rotateTimer = timer( ...etc.) end

Answer (score 0):

I could not arrive at a solution to this problem by "resetting" the timer object, as I had intended.

The solution that does work:

- I have a repeating timer object that triggers at a fixed interval (0.5 s) once logging has been enabled.
- When the logging is first enabled, I call `tic()` and save its result.
- Within the timer's callback function, I call `toc()` to check the elapsed time since logging began. If the elapsed time exceeds the rotation threshold, I execute a log rotation. The log rotation calls `tic()` to "reset" the time since rotation to 0.
- When the user manually rotates the logs, I call `tic()` to "reset" the time since rotation to 0 and execute a log rotation.

This works well enough for my purposes. The timing jitter between log rotations is about 1 second, but this is acceptable to me. I could reduce the period of my timer object to reduce the jitter if desired.

Comment: Oleg, I'm sorry. I should have accepted your answer as it's a perfectly good solution. I chose my method because I already had a timer object firing every 1/2 second so it was easy to piggyback off it.

Comment: It's ok, I just wanted to know if my solution was meeting your needs and if it was clear. Also, I think your question is interesting and I was surprised myself that the most obvious answer was deleting the timer and re-creating it.